# Redirect on local notification click in ionic not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

So I have local notifications setup using ngCordovas local notification plugin. They are firing and getting received by the application. However after that I cannot seem to redirect to the specific page I want to. Here is my relevant code, the console.log inside of the click event is firing, and the commented out code will redirect to the page but it is outside of ionic at that point (css not loading, js not bootstrapping etc)

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova', 'ionic-numberpicker', 'ngStorage'])
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider){
    $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
  })
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $cordovaLocalNotification) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $rootScope.$on("$cordovaLocalNotification:click", function(notification, $state) {
      console.log('clicked notification');
      //window.location.href = 'templates/notification.html';
      $state.go('notification');
    });

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    cache:false,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.settings', {
    url: '/settings',
    cache:false,
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html',
        controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.list', {
      url: '/list',
      cache:false,

    views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
          controller: 'ListCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.home', {
      url: '/home',
      cache:false,

      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
          controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.contact', {
      url: '/contact',
      cache:false,

      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/contact.html',
          controller: 'ContactCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('app.user', {
    url: '/users/:userId',
    cache:false,

    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/users.html',
        controller: 'UsersCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
    .state('notification', {
      url: '/notification',
      cache:false,
      templateUrl: 'templates/notification.html',
      controller: 'NotificationCtrl'
    });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$state.go('notification') actually works if you import the state in the .run function instead of the click function itself.